# How to avoid running argument function before the main function

Tags: python

I want to create a function that will react according to the success of the argument function and get the argument function's name.

Something like

```py
def foo(argument_function):
    try:
        argument_function
        print(f"{somehow name of the argument_function} executed successfully.")
    except:
        print(f"{somehow name of the argument_function} failed.")
```

1. argument_function should be executed only under the try statement. Otherwise, it will give an error and stop the script which I am trying to avoid.
2. {somehow name of the argument_function} should return the name of the argument_function.

for successful attempt:

```
foo(print("Hello world!"))
```

should return

```
>>Hello world!
>>print("Hello world!") executed successfully.
```

for unsuccessful attempt:

```
foo(prnt("Hello world!"))
```

should return

```
>>prnt("Hello world!") failed.
```

Comment: `foo(print("Hello world!"))` is not the function `foo` with an argument `print`. First `print("Hello world!")` is evaluated. Then `foo` is called with the argument `None` (the return value of `print`).

Comment: Yes Matthias, actually I am exactly trying to change the evaluation order. Bring the function whichever is given as an argument without evaluating into the function then evaluate inside.

Answer (score 2):

```
import typing
def foo(argument_function:typing.Callable):
    try:
        argument_function()
        print(f"{argument_function.__name__} executed successfully.")
    except:
        print(f"{argument_function.__name__} failed.")
print(foo.__name__) # returns foo
```

Or use:

```
def foo(argument_function:callable):
```

`__name__` returns function name and if you ensure the function is an object then adding `()` should run the function

Comment: `object` does not guarantee that the argument is callable.  I would using [`typing.Callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable) or the built-in [`callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#callable) function instead.

Comment: good point thank you will revise

Comment: I tried:
import typing
def foo(argument_function:typing.callable):
    try:
        argument_function()
        print(f"{argument_function.__name__} executed successfully.")
    except:
        print(f"{argument_function.__name__} failed.")

foo(print("hey"))
it returned an error:
      1 import typing
----> 2 def foo(argument_function:typing.callable):
      3     try:
      4         argument_function()

AttributeError: module 'typing' has no attribute 'callable'

Comment: no success? was there an error on __name__ and NoneType?

Comment: callable is a builtin

Comment: ```typing.Callable``` is another

Comment: I changed it and it returns error for argument_function.__name__ part although print hey successfuly. Here the error: 
      5     print(f"{argument_function.__name__} executed successfully.")
      6 except:
----> 7     print(f"{argument_function.__name__} failed.")

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__name__'